# CakePHP - I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error messages, with the occasional 404 when trying to fix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.3

I've been working with cakePHP for a while now, and there's an error that keeps appearing occasionally that I have been unable to find a fix for.

The issue is, in some servers cakephp seems to return a 500 Internal Server Error, even when the same software works in most other servers. This has become an issue because apparently the error is now appearing in GoDaddy servers, which, being the most common server, is what I would expect many of our customers to use. Also I know this isn't a coding issue since the error will appear both with our software and with new, empty cakePHP packages as downloaded from [here](http://cakephp.org/downloads).

That said, I have already tried changing the .htaccess files to fit what described [here](http://designaeon.com/2014/07/cakephp-godaddy-htaccess-fix/), to no avail. As of this moment the .htaccess files for the test (codeless, should only output a cakephp release notes page) install look like this:

The one on **/caketest/** (That's the subfolder I'm installing on):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on
     # Rewrite Base: The Base Path For Domain
     RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The one on **/caketest/app/**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1/    [L]
</IfModule>
```

The one on **/caketest/app/webroot/**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

With this change to the default cakephp .htaccess files, the 500 Internal Server Error page disappears. However, now I get a 404 page saying:

> The requested URL /app/webroot/ was not found on this server.

Then, I tried changing the **/caketest/** .htaccess file to match the subfolder it's in:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on
     # Rewrite Base: The Base Path For Domain
     RewriteBase /caketest/

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

But then I start getting the 500 Internal Server Error issue again. I've spent all morning looking over the web for possible solutions to this issue, but I can't seem to find any. Any threads have either gone unanswered or have the same solution I've already tried to no avail. I'm at the end of my wits here, can anyone help with this?

Comment: A 500 error means you need to go and look in your Apache error log. It will be stated in detail there.

Comment: I already looked at /logs/ and there's nothing mentioning any errors on the January 2015 file.

Comment: You mean /tmp/logs, right?

Comment: Server I'm working on doesn't seem to have a /logs/ folder inside /tmp. It's not a godaddy server in this case, but the company's main server that has been having the same issue for months (And we had ignored thinking it was only this server). I'm not really good with server architecture and how they work, I just code in them so sorry if I'm not going the right way here :\

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the default .htaccess. nothing more, nothing less.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It will remove the statusCode:500 and you are good to continue..